# Want to post from a Apps Script form to another App Script

Tags: html, post, google-apps-script, sidebar, add-on

I have an addon shared to all domain-users.
It opens a sidebar that contains a form.

I want the form to post to another Apps Script (implemented webapp) in a basic client-server fashion.
The other script (runs as admin) should do stuff with the user-submitted data.

Script1.html (in addon, any user can run it)

```
<form id="myForm" method="post" action="https://script.google.com/a/macros/<domain>/s/<script2-id>/exec">
  <input name="name" type="text" value=""/>   
  <input name="message" type="text" value=""/>
  <input type="button" value="send" formmethod="post" onclick="google.script.host.close();" />
</form>
```

Script2 (always runs by same admin)

```
function doPost(formInfo){
  doStuff(formInfo.name,formInfo.message)
}
```

Is this possible? What am I doing wrong. Can this be done in a secure way?

Comment: Do you want the Web App to open up in the the current browser tab?  Open up in another browser tab?  Will the Web App already be open?  Is the Web App to get the updated information on a totally different computer?

Comment: Using `method="post"` with the IFRAME sandbox mode, with a submit button in the form, will cause the page to disappear.  If you want the web app to open in a new browser tab, you'll either need to use a link with `target=_blank`,  `<a href="http://www.google.com" target="_blank">Google</a>` or use one of the `window.location` DOM methods in the JavaScript client side code.

Comment: My issue is not with what the users get(), as much as with what they post(). I want to send data to the webapp, not receive from it.

Comment: Should I instead switch to having the html-form on the webapp-side and just fetching it into addon-sidebar. Isn't that less secure?

Comment: There is no difference in security either way.  If you want information from one user interface to instantly (or very quickly) be displayed by the other user interface, then which ever UI you want to show the data, needs to "poll" the data source on a constant basis.  If all you want to do save data from one place to another, and you are using a spreadsheet for data storage,  you can save data to any spreadsheet  you want, by opening the spreadsheet by ID.  [Google Documentation - Open by ID](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#openById(String))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works with no security (anyone can access, even anonymously) on the webapp. Otherwise it will force a Google Signin.

sidebar.html (from client-script.gs)

```
<form id="myForm" target="_self" method="post" action="https://script.google.com/macros/s/SCRIPT_ID/exec">
  <input name="name" type="text" value=""/>   
  <input name="message" type="text" value=""/>
  <input type="submit" value="send" />
</form>
```

Comment: This solution would be much better with domain-only-access for the webapp, but that problem is beyond me.